# some strange errors at the botttom in site

Tags: magento-1, performance, magento-1.7.0.1

our site is loading very very slow & if you scroll down to bottom of the page you can see these errors in image :

[image]

how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Do you have cache enabled ?

Comment: Also could you post the content of this file `app/design/frontend/default/galagiftshop/template/page/html/em_variation.phtml` please

Comment: i will check it....

Comment: These are not errors, it's simply the profiler that's activated.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism cache is enabled, i will post code in few minute.....

Comment: @JulienLachal will it work if we deactivate it ? how to de activate ?

Comment: I believe it's in the index.php at the root folder of your Magento. Look for profiler inside that file

Comment: @JulienLachal In the backend under System > Configuration > Developer

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Quite right (post it as an aswer ;) ). I assume I've been hardcoding it somewhere in the index.php for a quick profiler view based on my IP on a production site x)

Comment: @JulienLachal it was enabled in backend, now i disabled it, now errors which were present below are gone. 
but still i feel site is loading very very slow. please check once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing are not errors, they are the entries for the Magento profiler.

It can be enabled/disabled under **System > Configuration > Developers** as well as under the `index.php` file by uncommenting/commenting this line:

```
#Varien_Profiler::enable();
```

Comment: it was enabled in backend, now i disabled it, now errors which were present below in site are gone. but still i feel site is loading very very slow. please check once.

Comment: @use7639gu59305u well that's another issue please mark this question as solved and create a new question with the content of the template I mentioned in the comment ;)

Comment: i posted new question with code that you suggested.

Comment: you can check here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109602/site-is-loading-very-very-slow-and-menu-header-part-missing-in-home-page